# How to sqrt a number and if its a decimal, give a different output

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to write some python code where it performs a sqrt on a give number.  Realizing that some situations might simply spit out a decimal (which I don't want).  How do I check or what code should I add to determine whether the result is a whole number or a decimal in the code before it decides what to do with it?

This question is different as it is not a list and that question was how to do so in a list, not how to ensure the accuracy of the square root function.

Comment: How large are the numbers that you want to check?

Comment: How large can it go? I'd say no less than 256 bit numbers... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you check `if int(num) == num:`. That should work.

```
from decimal import *
getcontext().prec = 20 #It represents the precision. Increase it if you need.
num = Decimal(num).sqrt()
if int(num) == num:
    print 'whole number'
else:
    pass
```

Comment: @JohnColeman what do you mean?  I just want to know if the input number is a perfect square or not.  This seems to work, but maybe I'm wrong.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am really sorry for sloppy work. I am new to stackoverflow. I deleted `num =` part by mistake, while indenting. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. I am really sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

Would a conditional such as that found below suffice?

```
import math

def alternativeSqrt(x):
    num  = x**0.5
    if math.floor(num) == num:
        return num
    else:
        return f(x)
```

Comment: I'm not sufficiently familiar with that "x**0.5" to be absolutely sure.  The previous answer did work, but I would, admittedly, prefer something that is more definitive.  Like a modular square root which would either fail or provide a completely different number.  I overloaded python when I set the precision "too high" I guess with the previous answer.  the script suddenly took up 25gigs of ram in a couple of seconds and nearly crashed my computer.

Comment: To my knowledge, x**0.5 == sqrt(x)

Comment: Oh oh oh!  I think you're right.  Okay, that makes sense.